# Navigation on one page website linking to wrong place

Tags: html, html-lists

http://joshhornby.co.uk/skinnybeer/index.html

As you can see when you click on 'The Booze' in scrolls down to the first item in the container not the area where the div is.

The nav html is

```
<li><a href="#booze">The Booze</a></li>
```

and linking to a div id called booze.

```
<div id="booze">
```

It seems to be linking to the image or the container and I am not sure how to make it scroll to the header not the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is linking to #booze, you just have a `position: fixed` element covering it up.

[image: Screenshot]